# Как осуществить translate картинки с добавлением значения?

Tags: javascript, position, transform

**Приветствую.**

У меня есть проблема с добавлением значения (целочисленного) в пикселях к уже существующему значению позиции.
Тоесть, вкратце, **мне нужно, чтобы картинка сдвинулась по итогу со своей current позиции на 5 пикселей в разные стороны.**
Надеюсь, понятно всё объяснил, прошу помочь мне.

Думаю, проблема решается достаточно просто, но почему-то не могу найти нигде решения на эту тему, **спасибо!**

**JavaScript-структура:**

```
// Вызываю обработчик событий на опускание клавиши (для передвижения картинки на зажим клавиши)
document.addEventListener('keydown', newHeart_func);
 
// Беру координаты картинки
let pos = newHeart.getBoundingClientRect();
 
// Основная функция изменения позиции
// Нужно сделать так, чтобы позиция высчитывалась с помощью getBoundingClientRect().
function newHeart_func(event) {
    if (event.key == 'w') {
        newHeart.style.transform = 'translateY(-5px)';
    } else if (event.key == 'a') {
        newHeart.style.transform = 'translateX(-5px)';
    } else if (event.key == 's') {
        newHeart.style.transform = 'translateY(5px)';
    } else if (event.key == 'd') {
        newHeart.style.transform = 'translateX(5px)';
     }
}
```

Comment: что значит "сдвинулась в разные стороны"?

Answer (score 1):

Держите основные данные в переменных, а потом ими оперируйте. Например:

```
let moveDelta = 5;
let directionData = {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
};
```

и потом применяйте:

```
if (event.key == 'w') {
    directionData.top -= moveDelta;        
} else if (event.key == 'a') {
    directionData.left -= moveDelta;        
} else if (event.key == 's') {
    directionData.top += moveDelta;        
} else if (event.key == 'd') {
    directionData.left += moveDelta;        
}

newHeart.style.transform = `translate(${directionData.left}px, ${directionData.top}px)`;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Интересное решение вопроса.